# python extract text description from large text file

Tags: python

i have bigg text file, and i need extract description message :

```
#### **Description**

20_Ways_To_Make_100_Dollars_EVERYDAY !!!  
High Quality Guide (PDF File)  
Here; I will teach you how to make 100 dollars every, or may be even more!  
Buy the guide to get this secret method. ! worth more than you pay!  
Good luck to everyone!



#### **Ships To**

Worldwide
```

start to "**Description**" finish to "#### **Ships To**", how can i make this whit python ? i need this output :

```
20_Ways_To_Make_100_Dollars_EVERYDAY !!!  
High Quality Guide (PDF File)  
Here; I will teach you how to make 100 dollars every, or may be even more!  
Buy the guide to get this secret method. ! worth more than you pay!  
Good luck to everyone!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have more variety in messages after '####' I would suggest to use stricter format criteria while parsing your file:

```
import re #regular expressions module

file = open('text_to_process.txt', 'r') #opening your file

text = file.readlines()

file.close()

flag = False #flag to mark start/end of description

for line in text:
    if re.match(r"#### \*\*Description\*\*", line):
        flag = True
        continue
    if flag: 
        if not re.match("####", line):
            print(line.strip()) #just printing the line, alternatively you could write it into file or variable
        else:
            flag = False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that that's exactly how the titles will look, try:

```
In_description = false
Part = ""
For line in file:
    If not in_description:
        In_description = '**Description**' in line
    If in_description:
        In_description = not '**Ships to**' in line
        If in_description:
            Part += line
```

Apologies for some of the capitalisation errors, I'm on a phone. What this code does is (assuming you have an open file), read through each line looking to turn in_description to true. When it is true, make sure it's not that last line, and if it isn't, write that line to the file. I'm not online, so I'm not 100% sure on if you need a '/n' at the end of line (ie if you need "part + '/n'"), but if it all comes out in one line, then you need it. I'd advise changing those constants to be as specific as possible as well, include a number of #s.

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate through the file until the `Description` line found, and then
- Print lines until the `Ships To` line is found

---

```
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    # iterate through f until Description line found
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#### **Description**'):
            break
    # print lines until Ships To line is found
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#### **Ships To**'):
            break
        print(line)
```

---

[`break` terminates the `for-loop`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). But since `f` is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), the next `for-loop` begins where the other `for-loop` left off. So the two `for-loop`s are together only making one pass through the file.